# Are these objects equal?

Tags: javascript, mootools

```
var Widget = new Class({
    Implements: Options,
    options: {
        color: '#fff',
        size: {
            width: 100,
            height: 100
        }
    },
    initialize: function(options){
        this.setOptions(options);
    }
});

var myWidget = new Widget({
    color: '#f00',
    size: {
        width: 200
    }
});

//myWidget.options is now: {color: #f00, size: {width: 200, height: 100}}

// Deep copy example
var mySize = {
    width: 50,
    height: 50
};

var myWidget = new Widget({
    size: mySize
});

(mySize == myWidget.options.size) // false! mySize was copied in the setOptions call.
```

from [here](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class.Extras)

myWidget.options.size should be also

```
 {
        width: 50,
        height: 50
    };
```

Why is (mySize == myWidget.options.size) // false! ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that won't work because it doesn't checks the values of the objects, but the identity of the objects:

```
({width:1, height:1}) == ({width:1, height:1})
```

So if you want to compare two object you have to write something like that

```
obj1.width == obj2.width && obj1.height == obj2.height;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not to be obvious, but the comment that you copied from the example tells you why.

```
// false! mySize was copied in the setOptions call.
```

Equals on an object is to the instance.  setOptions copies the mySize.  It runs when it is initialized.

```
initialize: function(options){
    this.setOptions(options);
}
```

Unless you are asking a more complex question that I missed.

Comment: What does it mean it copies it?? why is their identity different??

Answer (score 0):

comparing 2 objects is meaningless as stated by @styrr but you can compare the serialised representation of the objects instead:

```
console.log(JSON.encode(mySize) === JSON.encode(myWidget.options.size)); // true
```

though you are better off comparing individual values, it's cheaper.

Also, look into `Object.clone()` to dereference. By default, objects are passed by reference but in the case of options, they are dereferenced. I.E. if you change `mySize.width`, it won't change `instance.options.size.width`, which you would get normally.

Answer (score 0):

Use underscorejs.js isEqual to compare JSON objects http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual